# Reinstall phpMyAdmin (Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost')

Tags: nginx, phpmyadmin

I have used this command to reconfigure **phpMyAdmin**

`sudo dpkg-reconfigure phpmyadmin`

I check neither **apache2** neither **lighttpd**.
I enter root password, two times.
And I have this error:

> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using
>   password: NO)

How can I reinstall phpMyAdmin on Nginx?

Comment: Was your mysql command thus: `mysql -u root -p`?

Comment: This is asking for your `mysql` `root` user password.

Comment: If I type this command: `mysql -u root -p` I can access to mysql on console with my root MySQL password.